# How to translate “call on”?

Tags: traduction, usage

Si on est dans la classe et le professeur choisit tel ou tel étudiant, soit pour lui permettre de poser une question, soit pour lui indiquer que c’est lui, l’étudiant, qui est censé répondre à une question ou prendre une action quelconque, comment est-ce qu’on décrit l’acte de langage que met en œuvre le professeur?

En anglais (aux ÉU, au moins) on dirait, « The teacher *called on* the student. »

Comment: "Le professeur appela l'élève (au tableau)", ou bien "Le professeur posa la question à l'élève", ou encore "Le professeur mit l'élève au pied du mur". "Le professeur coinca l'élève". "Le professeur demanda à l'élève (d'essuyer le tableau)"

Comment: @Frank: tes suggestions sont à mon avis pour la plupart trop connotées. *Call on* c'est (dans ce contexte) synonyme de *ask/request*, « poser la question » est trop spécifique (il ne s'agit pas forcément de répondre à une question), si on ne veut pas utiliser « demander », « faire appel » serait une alternative.

Comment: @None Oui, j'ai essayé de couvrir le plus de situations possibles. Il faudrait un peu plus de contexte pour savoir de quelle "action" il s'agit. Oh! Mais j'ai mal lu! Il s'agit de _laisser l'élèver poser une question_! Hmmm. Difficile. "Le professeur se tourna vers l'étudiant pour l'inviter à poser une question"? "Le professeur invita l'élève à poser une question"? On est dans la périphrase ...

Comment: @None "Le professeur fit appel à un élève" me paraît très bien, mais du coup, on a l'impression que le professeur demande à l'élève de lui rendre un service plutôt que de poser une question, à mon avis.

Comment: @Frank *laisser l'élève poser une question!* **ou** « prendre une action quelconque » (je suppose que le PO veut dire « faire quelque chose », « agir ) (*take an action* in English).

Comment: Du point de vue de celui qui est called on, si ce fait conforme à ses désirs, il aurait peut-être levé la main. On the other hand, in many situations an English speaker might vouloir éviter being called on car il ne sait pas la réponse, car il na’a pas fait ses devoirs, car il est timide, ….          And oops, I **did** write “prendre une action.”  None m’a bien compris.

Comment: @None - oui: Le professeur laissa l'élève poser une question. S'il ne s'agit que de poser une question, pas de problème. Mais ça ne marche plus pour une "action quelconque".

Comment: @Frank heu...je te citais  (*laisser l'élève poser une question*) et je citais le PO (*prendre une action quelconque) pour montrer l'alternative (**ou**) (*take action*). Je ne propose pas du tout  *Le professeur laissa l'élève poser une question*. Pour moi *call on* dans ce cas c'est « demander/faire appel à ». ( Le prof fit appel à l'élève pour.../demanda à l'élève de ...)

Comment: @None Désolé pour toute cette confusion :-)

Comment: _Faire appel à_ et _appeler à_ sont certainement utiles. Mais l'acte est possiblement une _interpellation_.

Comment: Suivant le contexte, le professeur peut "donner la parole à l'élève", "le questionner", "l'interroger" ou le "mettre sur la sellette".

Answer (score 1):

Selon le contexte "call on" se traduit en général en français par *interroger*, *faire appel à* ou *demander*.

Prenons trois situations où en anglais j'utiliserais "call on".

1- Quand il s'agit d'obtenir une réponse à une question :

> Les professeurs *interrogent* souvent les élèves qui ne lèvent pas la main parce qu'ils pensent qu'ils ne sont pas attentifs.<sup>1</sup>

2- Quand il s'agit de faire faire quelque chose à quelqu'un :

> Ils ont *fait appel* à moi pour organiser la soirée.
> Ils m'*ont demandé* d'organiser la soirée.<sup>2</sup>

3 - *Faire appel* induit une idée de service que l'on demande à quelqu'un, *demander* est presque ressenti comme un obligation, un ordre, c'est pourquoi je ne l’emploierais pas dans le contexte suivant où il s'agit quasiment d'un ordre dans le but d'obtenir une action :

> L'organisation de défense des droits humains a demandé aux États-Unis de mettre fin à la peine de mort. <sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1. Teachers often call on the students who aren't raising their hands to see if they are paying attention.</sup>
<sup>2. They called on me to organize the party.</sup>
<sup>3. The human rights group has called on the US to end the death penalty.</sup>

Comment: Pour le dernier exemple, on imagine bien aussi la même phrase avec "appeler à". "L'organisation (...) a appelé à mettre fin à la peine de mort aux Etats-Unis"

Comment: @XouDo Les deux phrases n'ont pas le même sens. « a demandé aux États-Unis de mettre fin à la peine de mort" → la demande est faite explicitement aux États-Unis, État-Unis est un COI.  », « ...a appelé à mettre fin à la peine de mort aux États-Unis .. » → la demande est faite à une entité non nommée (dont peuvent, bien sûr faire partie les État-Unis, mais pas que)  et  État-Unis est ici complément de lieu.